# DataTables: Add a row for totals and a row for percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following which does the one of the tasks i.e. adds a total row with the totals of each column. The last column is the total for each row so the last column in the footer is actually the total number

```
"footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
    var api = this.api(), data;
    var colNumber =Array.from(Array(45+1).keys()).slice(1);
           
    var intVal = function (i) {
        return typeof i === 'string' ? i * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
    };

    for (i = 0; i < colNumber.length; i++) {
        var colNo = colNumber[i];
        var total = api.column(colNo).data().reduce(function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0);
        $(api.column(colNo).footer()).html(total);
    }
}
```

What I need in addition to the above is another row adding in the footer that shows a percentage for each column total

I don't know where to start - any advice?

Thanks